date and time column sorter in excel
I know its a dum question, but I have data in excel in a very stupid format, I have usage data where my columns are half hourly basis and rows are dates for 1 year.

I need to see the dates and the corresponding half hour in the rows instead of columns and rows. Just like below. Dont want to do it manually as this is for 3 seprate account which would mean doing it 900+ times.

Thanks,
Vicky
